# unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path, MB Pro M1 Max. There is no Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

```
Building localstack
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hidden_app_name/docker/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

this is what I'm getting after trying to run `docker-compose up -d`

The error is pretty straighforward, but the service localstack does not have any Dockerfile.

```
localstack:
    build:
      context: ./docker
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "4571:4571"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,ses,rekognition
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      - './.localstack:/tmp/localstack'
      - './.aws:/root/.aws'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

Any ideas if this is related to the M1 Max Docker or anything like that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no Dockerfile, then there is nothing to build, therefore there is no context needed. Context is what is sent to the docker daemon at build time.

You should remove this from your docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
build:
      context: ./docker
```

Comment: Yes! You're right! And I'm blind that I've did not notice this context param. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11280830/mihai) is correct

You should remove this from your docker-compose.yml:

```
build:
      context: ./docker
```

Comment: That's what the upvotes are for!